# Unable to drag dojo floating pane

Tags: drag, dojo

I have two dojo buttons, which on click create floating panes. Now the 'Search' button creates a floating pane which does not move but the 'Mapping the Data' button's floating pane works fine. Till the time I do not drag the floating pane created by 'Mapping the Data', I am not able to drag the floating pane created by 'Search'.

This is my [application](http://msgist2011.grd.arizona.edu/project/tp_dock.html).

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the problem of `z-index`, *Search* is located beneath of your map (because of no `z-index` specified). When you open and drag *Mapping the Data* it sets `z-index:104` also to the *Search* which makes it moveable.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks, that did solve the problem. Only issue is that I did not assign any `z-index` to Mapping the Data floating pane then how did it get the 104 value?
`<div dojoType="dojox.layout.FloatingPane" title="Mapping the Data" id="floater" dockTo="dock" style="visibility:hidden;" closable="false" resizable="true" dockable="false" >`